Почему не работает callback в Телеграм боте?
подскажите, начал писать бота и столкнулся с такой проблемой, не работает @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True), хотя буквально неделю назад было все нормально. В чем может быть проблема? очень жду ваших вариантов!! прилагаю простой код, где на мой взгляд, все понятно и скорее он должен работать, чем нет, но этого не происходит(
import telebot
from telebot import types
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler()
def get_mess(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    but3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Текст', callback_data='txt')
    markup.add(but3)
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Мой текст', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_message(call):
    if call.data == 'txt':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Отправляю текст")


bot.polling(none_stop=True)

